# How to subtract a row from another row in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am new in R and trying to `subtract` a `country value` across the years `from another country` by using latest `gapminder dataset` (i.e a row subtraction from another row).

**dataset**

```
gapminder_new %>% 
  filter(country == c("India","Bangladesh"))

########## output ############

country 1960 1961 1962 1963   1964 1965  1966  1967
<chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>

Bangladesh  372 384 394 381 411 405 402 382 
India       330 336 339 352 370 353 345 365
```

I have tried many different combinations both from base & pipe but nothing have worked out.

**Initial failed attempts**

```
gapminder_new %>% 
  filter(country == c("India","Bangladesh")) %>% 
  .[country == "India",] - .[country == "Bangladesh",]

###################

gapminder_new %>% 
  filter(country == c("India","Bangladesh")) %>% 
  mutate(Diff_result = (. %>% filter(country == "India") ) - (. %>% filter(country == "Bangladesh"))  )

###################

gapminder_new[country == "India",] - gapminder_new[country == "Bangladesh",]
```

After this I realized that it could be a **problem because country name can't be subtracted as they are chars**, so i should **eliminate them from subtraction and use them as row index only** just like in python.

So I tried below code but even that is not working:

**Subtracting by row index**

```
# setting a row index
rownames(gapminder_new) <- gapminder_new$country

# subtracting only numerical col using row index
gapminder_new["India", 2: ncol(gapminder_new)] - gapminder_new["Bangladesh", 2: ncol(gapminder_new)]
```

**How do I fix this in both base R and by using pipes ???**

Daily i get stuck in 10 different data manipulation task in R. Somewhere we need to pull(), somewhere one has to choose only .[[]] but not at other spots. Where are all these rules defined at one place ?

I don't know why R is so complicated in things to choose from right from base R to pipes, from individual ML packages to caret to tidymodels to so many other things. Now I really feel that Python was much simpler, easier to learn and took very short time in learning in comparison to R.

**(UPDATE: This is what I finally used and also posted detail in answers)**

```
#convert to data frame
gapminder_new <- as.data.frame(gapminder_new)

# set country row index
rownames(gapminder_new) <- gapminder_new$country

# subtracting only numerical col using row index
gapminder_new["India", 2: ncol(gapminder_new)] - gapminder_new["Bangladesh", 2: ncol(gapminder_new)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
> gapminder_new %>% select(-1) %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~lead(.x) - (.x))) %>% na.omit()
# A tibble: 1 x 8
  `1960` `1961` `1962` `1963` `1964` `1965` `1966` `1967`
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1    -42    -48    -55    -29    -41    -52    -57    -17
>
```

Data used:

```
> gapminder_new
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  country    `1960` `1961` `1962` `1963` `1964` `1965` `1966` `1967`
  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Bangladesh    372    384    394    381    411    405    402    382
2 India         330    336    339    352    370    353    345    365
>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are filtering more than one value you should use `%in%` and not `==`.

Apart from that so many times data manipulation becomes very easy when you have data in right format. For example, for your case it would be much easier if you have data as 2 columns which are the name of the countries.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tmp <- gapminder_new %>%
         pivot_longer(cols = -country) %>%
         pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = value)
tmp

# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  name  Bangladesh India
#  <chr>      <int> <int>
#1 1960         372   330
#2 1961         384   336
#3 1962         394   339
#4 1963         381   352
#5 1964         411   370
#6 1965         405   353
#7 1966         402   345
#8 1967         382   365
```

Now getting the difference between two countries is as simple as :

```
tmp %>% mutate(diff = India - Bangladesh)

#  name  Bangladesh India  diff
#  <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
#1 1960         372   330   -42
#2 1961         384   336   -48
#3 1962         394   339   -55
#4 1963         381   352   -29
#5 1964         411   370   -41
#6 1965         405   353   -52
#7 1966         402   345   -57
#8 1967         382   365   -17
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, Yea I agree its easier to work with data in longer format and I have always been doing that till now. 
But i wanted to get out of comfort zone and do some row wise operations as many time when dataset is really huge then I felt its not a good idea to reshape data twice just for some subtraction or other computations.

Answer (score 0):

as you asked for a way to do it without piping here is one:

```
gapminder_new %>% 
  filter(country == c("India","Bangladesh")) # this is your code, rest without piping

gapminder_new[1,]<-gapminder_new[1,]*-1

gapminder_new<-apply(gapminder_new, 2, sum)
```

Comment: I am not sure if its working because this is giving me errors: 
```{r}
test_set <- gapminder_new %>% 
  filter(country %in% c("India","Bangladesh")) 

test_set[1,]<-test_set[1,]*-1

test_set<-apply(test_set, 2, sum)
```

but I have got the point from this as how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which I was trying earlier and failed probably because of tibble.

One just needs to set `country` as `rownames` in data frmae and then you can subtract based on country names in base R. That's it. It's a very basic approach for someone who is just starting and doesn't know any fancy functions.

**df**

```
gapminder_new         # latest gapminder data taken from gapminder website

########## output #########
country 1960 1961 ...... 2019
<chr> <dbl> <dbl> ...... <dbl>

1   Afghanistan NA  NA  
2   Albania NA  NA  
3   Algeria 2480    2090
```

**covert it to `data frame` and set `country` as `row names / row index`**

```
test_set <- as.data.frame(gapminder_new)
rownames(test_set) <- test_set$country

head(test_set)
######## output ########
            country 1960 1961 1962
            <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>

Afghanistan Afghanistan NA  NA  NA  
Albania     Albania NA  NA  NA  
Algeria     Algeria 2480    2090    1640
```

**subtract based on required country names**

```
test_set["India",2:ncol(test_set)] - test_set["Bangladesh",2:ncol(test_set)]

######### output ########
1960 1961 1962 1963 1964 1965 1966 1967 1968
India   -42 -48 -55 -29 -41 -52 -57 -17 -37
```